# how to make 3 nested loops in asm

Tags: assembly, nested-loops

I want to make 3 nested loops in asm, but i have not found any description. I want to solve this:

### [image]

This project is "finding the Pythagoras-triplets".

Comment: What is this _"description"_ that you speak of? Seems to me like the way to to this would be to either use a C++ compiler to generate assembly, or to learn assembly language programming for whatever processor architecture you're targeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how a typical loop could look like:

```
 mov ax,1
AgainA:
 ...
 inc ax
 cmp ax,1000
 jbe AgainA
```

Now imagine that you replace the ellipses with similar code but using the `BX` register. Later replace the new ellipses again with similar code using the `CX` register. Now you'll have 3 nested loops.
The last remaining ellipses will be replaced by the body of your program, the `IF` part.